# Passing Data to Twitter Bootstrap Modal in Angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-bootstrap

I want to show a modal box asking the user if they want to delete a post or not. I can't figure out how to pass the key which I pass in the key argument in which I also can alert.

I took the code from the angular twitterbootstrap site but I can't figure out a method to pass data to confirm the remove.

Thanks
Mohammad

```
$scope.deletePost = function(key, post, event) {
    alert(key);
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'deletePost.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
            items: function() {
                return $scope.posts;
            }
        },
    })

    modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        alert(selectedItem);
    });
};


var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.selected = {
        item: $scope.items[0]
    };
    $scope.ok = function() {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Send the key via resolve as a parameter (see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Om8rlM4SjV6U8pCx9iHV?p=preview)):

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  var key = 1000;
  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        },
        key: function() {return key; }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
};

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items, key) {

  alert("The key is " + key)
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks that is the what I was looking for, passing the key to the modal controller

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [Bootstrap components](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) written by the AngularUI Team. you can find a great set of Twitter Bootstrap components including Modal control.

**Example:**

html:

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
};

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/xIjUONEVhY5lO2kLhV4f?p=preview